# Android WebView: database.readTransaction results in a TypeError exception

Tags: javascript, android, database, html, webview

I have a HTML5 database `App.val.DB` that I would like to perform a select statement on using `App.val.DB.readTransaction`. This works fine on BlackBerry/PlayBook/Chrome, but on Android (within a WebView) it results in the following TypeError exception.

```
06-21 00:36:07.276: D/NotepadActivity(387): TypeError: Result of expression 'App.val.DB.readTransaction' [undefined] is not a function. -- From line 271 of file:///android_asset/script/main.js
```

Here is the related JavaScript:

```
      if(App.val.DB != null) {
            App.val.DB.readTransaction(
                function (t) {t.executeSql("SELECT * FROM " + App.schema.tableName + " ORDER BY "+App.schema.date+" DESC, "+App.schema.ID+" DESC", 
                        [], 
                        function (t, res) { /* Success */
                            App.log("Success");
                        },  
                        function (t, err) { /* Error */
                            App.log("Fail");
                        }
                    );
                }
            );
        } else {
            App.log("Database was NULL");
        }
```